# Is there a better way of sequentially calling dissimilar observable calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two API methods:

- `POST` /articles/{id}/revisions
- `GET` /articles/{id}

The result of posting to revisions is a revision document, which includes before/after changes to an article object. It is not an article object.

These correspond to the following methods in my Angular app:

- `this.endpoint.articles.revise(article.id, revisionParams);`
- `this.endpoint.articles.getById(article.id);`

Which return `Observable<ArticleRevision>` and `Observable<Article>`, respectively.

When I revise a document, I want to pull an updated copy of the document which has my changes. At the moment I'm able to achieve this by performing the following:

```
private reviseArticle(article: article, revisionParams: ArticleRevisionParams): Observable<Article> {
    return this.endpoint.articles.revise(article.id, revisionParams)
        .expand(r => this.endpoint.articles.getById(article.id))
        .pipe(take(2))
        .last();
}
```

From the description or [`expand`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html), it sounds like this method is more of a hack than a solution:

> Recursively call provided function.

I tried to use `concat`, but found that it requires observables of the same type, which was a bit of a show stopper in my case. Am I misusing `expand`, or is there a better (more correct) way to sequentially chain dissimilar observables?

<sub>P.S. I tagged Angular in case the Angular-bundled flavour of rxjs is slightly different to regular rxjs. Feel free to remove it if it doesn't belong.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I believe Angular is using the same rxjs library as the rest of us based on [this package.json](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/package.json).

Luckily, rxjs offers a number of options for completing tasks in different ways. I personally have not used expand in this way, but it looks like a pretty neat implementation.

One way you could do this is to create a new interface to hold both of those types:

```
export interface MyTypes {
  rev: ArticleRevision;
  article: Article;
}
```

This way, you can return a single type from your stream by using the [switchMap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) and setting the value of both responses on the one type and returning the observable.

Rough draft:

```
export interface MyTypes {
  rev: ArticleRevision;
  article: Article;
}
private reviseArticle(article: article, revisionParams: ArticleRevisionParams): Observable<MyTypes> =>
  this.endpoint.articles.revise(article.id, revisionParams)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((rev: ArticleRevision) =>
        this.endpoint.articles.getById(article.id)
          .pipe(
            switchMap((art: Article) => ({
              rev: rev,
              article: art,
            })
          )
    );
```

You could also use switchMap to return an array of the two values as an observable (similar to above, just return them in an array).

Comment: So piping to `switchMap` allows me to switch out the revision result for the getById observable? Since it's a pipe, I assume that if `revise` fails, the observable will error out there and not execute the get?

Comment: Ah, yes. That's exactly how it works. Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: You say `use switchMap to return an array of the two values as an observable`. But in your code your not returning an array but an object.

Comment: I suggested two examples, and offered the one for the interface, but I can see how the example's location can be misleading. Editing

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this without a container type, you could take advantage of the [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) operator.

The idea is to compose the intermediate result so that it's made up of the result from your first request, as well as the result from your second request, which depends on your first one. Part of this composition will require you to turn the first request result into an observable, which you can do with [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of).

Subsequently, you can destructure the responses of each request from the single resulting array argument (i.e. `([reviseResult, getByIdResult]) => { ... }`).

```js
const { forkJoin, of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

function revise(id, params) {
  return of({ id, params, operation: 'revise' });
}

function getById(id) {
  return of({ id, operation: 'getById' });
}

revise(1).pipe(
  switchMap(reviseResult => forkJoin(of(reviseResult), getById(reviseResult.id))),  
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will this result in both http requests happening in parallel? I believe the desire is to get the article after the changes have completed.

Comment: @OneLunchMan, no, they won't happen in parallel. That's why the `forkJoin` exists inside the `switchMap` operator. If the former was outside, then yes, obviously the requests will be concurrent. However, the second request might depend on something returned by the first request. The solution I prescribed gives you the opportunity to consume anything you need from the first request response to make the second request and then have both the first and second request responses emitted as a single value for subscribers.

Comment: Oh right, nice! Thanks for the clarity on that, this is cleaner than my solution above and can be an accepted answer.

Comment: @OneLunchMan Your answer was actually closer to the result I wanted, so I accepted yours. Either way, this is also as good answer so I upvoted it too :)